# Getting 404 error in phonegap/cordova with whitelist installed

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, command-line-interface

I have the whitelist plugin installed however, Im getting a build discrepancy between what is compiled in Android Studio and what is compiled using the cli.

When I compile my application in Android Studio it runs perfectly fine and can access all webpages needed by my app.

However when I use the command:
cordova build android --release

I am getting 404 errors as if the whitelist plugin isnt installed.

We are using a remote machine that is dependent on the cli tools to build.
Im hoping someone on here has run into this issue and has some advice on it.

Thank you.